# iOS: Simple Physics for a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, quartz-2d, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIView` that a user drags around via setting its center in the `touchesMoved:` method.  When the user lets go, I want the `UIView` to fall off the screen according to how fast and what direction they were moving it in.

Do I need to somehow create a vector by comparing the `UIView`'s last center point to it's new center point? And subtract a fixed amount to the vector's y value every so often with a `NSTimer`?

Comment: If you're willing to go the extra mile there is an excellent post about [integrating physics into UIKit](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/physics-101-uikit-app-with-box2d-for-gravity/). That being said, @Legolas' suggestion of Cocos2D is a more complete solution.

Comment: If you use a UIPanGesture you can get velocity in view and that will give you the speed at which something is being dragged. As well as the location of where it has been dragged too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to a decent amount of physics in calculating

1. Speed of swipe
2. Direction of swipe

You will need to use the `touchesMoved` method along with a timer to track the amount of time for the swipe and also the co-ordinates for the new location of the object. This should be fairly straight forward. Once you are done finding those you can simply add a `UIAnimation` for the object to move to its new place.

~ **A suggestion:**

I would suggest that you have a look at `Cocos2D` and integrate the library with you app. You will not need to implement `touch delegate` methods and compute things yourself ~ there are libraries for that :) It has a lot of libraries especially for moving objects (or `sprites` if you wish to call them that way) and you have animation method like `easeInEaseOut`, etc.. that can be impacted on the moving object. If you are developing a game of some sort, have a look at `chipMunk` engine in Cocos2D as well.